# Using newer versions of Visual Studio to manage older SSIS projects

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I know that VS 2010 can target specific .NET Framework editions, but specifically...

Can I use VS2010 to support SSIS packages that need to be saved in 2005 format?

How about VS2008?

I am trying to determine which edition I need get a license for. I am hoping I can do everything in 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that Visual Studio 2010 is supported by SSIS yet (even with SQL 2008 R2 I use VS 2008).  However, if you have SSIS it should come with Visual Studio 2008.  It is called the Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) and it installs with SSIS.

As for targeting an older SSIS project, I believe 2008 will target 2005.  You just need to install the SSIS management studio and you will have it.

Edit:  To be clear, BIDS 2008 will not be able to modify 2005 packages (I believe you can run them though).  You will need to install just BIDS (not the entire Visual Studio) for each version you want to modify.  Here is a link with more explanations:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/sqlintegrationservices/thread/4fe1b042-3f8d-473d-b9fe-2c4adeb67bcd

As for licensing specifically, you will need a developer license for SSIS at the version level you are trying to edit.  Therefore, if you are editing SSIS 2005 packages, you will need a 2005 SSIS developer license.  See more details here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/0b2754aa-716e-4f81-85c0-3b6dcdc34bb3/